# Avro field default values

Tags: java, maven, avro

I am running into some issues setting up default values for Avro fields. I have a simple schema as given below:

**data.avsc:**

```
{
 "namespace":"test",
 "type":"record",
 "name":"Data",
 "fields":[
    { "name": "id", "type": [ "long", "null" ] },
    { "name": "value", "type": [ "string", "null" ] },
    { "name": "raw", "type": [ "bytes", "null" ] }
 ]
}
```

I am using the *avro-maven-plugin v1.7.6* to generate the Java model.

When I create an instance of the model using:
`Data data = Data.newBuilder().build();`, it fails with an exception:

> org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException:
>   org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Field id type:UNION pos:0 not
>   set and has no default value.

But if I specify the "default" property,

```
{ "name": "id", "type": [ "long", "null" ], "default": "null" },
```

I do not get this error. I read in the documentation that first schema in the union becomes the default schema. So my question is, why do I still need to specify the "default" property? How else do I make a field optional?

And if I do need to specify the default values, how does that work for a union; do I need to specify default values for each schema in the union and how does that work in terms of order/syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The default value of a union corresponds to the first schema of the union ([Source](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/d/msg/cdk-dev/Xgo5YKEcQ1Q/VkyWP2gnOEMJ)). Your union is defined as `["long", "null"]` therefor the default value must be a long number. `null` is not a long number that is why you are getting an error.

If you still want to define `null` as a default value then put null schema first, i.e. change the union to `["null", "long"]` instead.

Comment: Simply putting null first in the type union does not make it optional it seems - that is how I had it and still got the error. Adding default null is required at least on Avro 1.7.5 which I'm using.

Comment: Check this: http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/avro/define-avro-schema-with-default-values/. Has a complete schema defined and field rules table. Covers every complex type being defaulted. Only missing 'record' field type, but applies the same: {"type": ["null", {"name": "", "type":"record", "fields":[]}]}

Comment: This is a very surprising behavior from Avro. I wish the error was more explicit about this

Comment: `Simply putting null first in the type union does not make it optional it seems - that is how I had it and still got the error. Adding default null is required at least on Avro 1.7.5 which I'm using.` This is correct, and by design. A `union {null, long} myField` is still a mandatory field, meaning that it needs to be set explicitly. The only difference with a `long myField` is that the latter can never get the value `null`.

Answer (score 52):

Its a **bug** at Avro's end which is marked as `Not A Problem` .
You need to add default attribute to mention default value.

```
{"name": "xxx", "type": ["null", "boolean"], "default": null}
```

Please refer [AVRO-1803](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1803).

Comment: For numeric values the default value must be null but when a string type it must be "null" - i.e "default": null} and "default": "null"}

Comment: what is the default value for bytes?

Comment: I would not call this a bug in Avro. You could argue that it is bad design, and it's definitely not intuitive to some people, but it's an intentional feature which is consistent with other rules in Avro. There *is* a conceptual and byte level difference between "this can be null" and "this can be null, and can be entirely missing, in which case it is assumed to be null". Avro's standard just requires that difference to be explicitly expressed in the schema instead of defining implicit defaults.

Answer (score 22):

You must provide `"default": null` not `"default": "null"` in the schema to get the builder method working

Comment: That's not the case for all types, such as string.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you are using builder,

According to the [documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html#Creating+Users) of the Java API:

> using a builder requires setting all fields, even if they are null

Comment: In my opinion this is what really answers the OP's question. The default value is ignored by Avro when encoding. What's happening is that the builder is allowing you to skip setting fields that have a default value. The default value is of no use to make a field optional. The following is enough:
{ "name": "id", "type": [ "long", "null" ]}