# How to merge hive table avro format with already existing main table having slightly different avro schema format

Tags: merge, hive, avro

There are 2 Hive avro formatted tables

Main_Table, Table_A

Main_Table already has data. Table_A avro schema has few additional columns compared to Main_Table. scenario is Table_A data has to be merged with Main_Table

columns in Table_A are dynamic, it might change after few days.

How to merge Table_A with Main_Table?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to add the columns missing in your main table (columns which are in table_a) using default values as null [Avro field default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938124/avro-field-default-values)