# How to use the Avro SchemaBuilder class to set a null default?

Tags: avro

I am creating schema programmatically, which is a requirement, using `SchemaBuilder` for example:

```
Schema s = SchemaBuilder.record(collectionName).namespace("com.company.something").fields()
  .name(field).type().nullable().stringType().noDefault()
  ...
  .endRecord();
```

This, however, creates a nullable field with no default. I'd like to make it default to null.
I don't understand how the API can be used to set a default, other than a string default, e.g. by using `stringDefault("default")` to replace `noDefault()`. Unfortunately, the argument cannot be null.

How is this achieved by this API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nullable field in Avro is a union of the field type + a null type. For some reason, a nullable field, e.g. `.name(field).type().nullable().stringType()` , generates a schema where the union is `["string", "null"]`.

It seems that the [first type of the union can control the default value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23387590/22180933), so a union like the above can have a default string value, but not a default null value. For that, you need a `["null", "string"]` union.

To get this, the API constructs you were using don't work. You need something like this:

```
.name(field).type().unionOf().nullType().and().stringType().endUnion().nullDefault()
```

It can be harder to figure it out from the API, because you need to realize that a union is used also in your snippet and that null needs to be first before you can attempt it. Since the snippet in the question and this look very different, people will get confused.